# Getting error while installing MkvToolNix old version on Debian Buster

Tags: debian, dpkg, deb, mkvtoolnix

I was trying to install an older version of MkvtoolNix (version 19) on Debian Buster, and it gives me the error below in GDebi . I also tried  `sudo dpkg -i` and it also gave some dependency errors, which i am not able to fix . This is the error I get with Gdebi:

```
Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: mkvtoolnix (= 9.8.0 dmo1)
```

Comment: Compile it then.

Comment: An alternative is to use an AppImage, MKVToolNix provides version 25 to current in this format [here](https://mkvtoolnix.download/appimage/).

Comment: I sure can use an Appimage , thans for your help sir

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered my question, ]

An alternative is to use an AppImage, MKVToolNix provides version 25 to current in this format here. – Loïc Reynie

Hence I have got the answer and thanks to everyone for helping me out